# php pass value contain question mark?

Tags: php, str-replace

i want to pass value that contain question mark

i have 2 php example example1.php and example2.php

in my example1.php the code like this

```
 <a href="example2.php?title=what is this?" />
```

in my example2.php the code like this

```
 <php
 if(isset($_GET['title']))
 {
  $title = $_GET['title'];
  echo $title;
 }

 ?>
```

but in example2.php the title become like this `what is this` the question mark disappear

i already try to use `str_replace` my question mark become like this `what is this"?"`  but still same at example2.php the question mark disappear

please help me how to pass value that contain question mark

thanks

Comment: use: %3F    search for URL encoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  `<a href="example2.php?title=what is this?" />` into

```
<a href="example2.php?title=what is this%3F" />
```

then add

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['title']))
 {
  $title = $_GET['title'];
  echo $title;
 }

 ?>
```

this will work for you.